# Cannot access redux state variables inside a function in reactjs without useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I know it looks like a silly question but I'm not able to understand why I'm not able to get a value of a Redux store variable into a function directly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Chat = ({ conversations, isLoggedIn, user, messages }) => {

//Not able to access the User Prop directly here... shows a blank object inside handleNewMessage 

  const handleNewMessage = (msg) => {
    console.log(user, "user");
   //Other stuffs
  };

   useEffect(() => {
     socket?.on("newMessage", (msg) => {
       handleNewMessage(msg);
   });
  }, [socket]);

  return <p>Message</p>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  messages: state.messages.messages,
  isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
  user: state.auth.user,
  conversations: state.conversations.conversations,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Chat);
```

I can't figure out why it shows a blank object for user. If I put a useEffect to watch if user is updating or not I'm getting the correct object.

Comment: use `useSelector` and check the rerender count and console the user object

Comment: Any chance your user reducer is mutating the user object instead of returning a new one? A common source of issues in redux apps.